# Laravel Blade some values in 2 dimensional input array missing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

i have a form that has editable answers, which are built like the following:

```html
@foreach ($question->answers as $answer)
<input type="text" name="answers[{{$loop->index}}][text]">
<input type="hidden" name="answers[{{$loop->index}}][id]" value="{{$answer->id}}">
@endforeach
```

Which generates the html

```html
<input type="text" name="answers[0][text]" value="Somevalue">
<input type="hidden" name="answers[0][id]" value="1">
<input type="text" name="answers[1][text]" value="Somevalue">
<input type="hidden" name="answers[1][id]" value="2">
```

In my Controller, I try to get the values from the request like this:

```
$requestAnswers = $request->input('answers');

foreach($requestAnswers as $key => $value) {
    $id = $value['id'];
    $text = $value['text'];
    // Some answer handling
}
```

Somehow, when I try to access my answers, even when I `dd($request->input('answers'))` only some values show up, sometimes not having a text, sometimes not appearing at all.

Is there an error in my code or is the problem related to something else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've shown here. I suggest checking the HTML when it *doesn't* work, and also use your browser's network inspector to confirm what data is being sent.

Comment: Thank you! I was unsure if I made an error since I'm unfamiliar with Laravel. I will search elsewhere